# Enable nvidia-smi permissions to be run by all users

Tags: gpu

How can I enable nvidia-smi for all users. I can run it as a sudo user, but as a regular user, I get:

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Insufficient Permissions
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the problem and here was my solution. Maybe it is helpful to you.

By `ll /dev/nvidia*` you can find that the devices belong to `root` and `vglusers` group.

If you are the same to me, now you should add your user account into the `vglusers` group.

by `usermod -a -G vglusers username` (require sudo)

or editing `/etc/group` and add your username at the end of the line `vglusers:x:****:user1,user2,...`

Then logout the bash and re-enter.

Notes:

- The group name may be `video` rather than `vglusers`; you'll see which name is used when you `ll /dev/nvidia*`.
- If you are using `vncserver`, you have to kill the server and restart it because you did not have the permission when you started the `vncserver`.

Answer (score 2):

If your issue is happening when attempting to run the command from within a docker container AND you have SELinux activated (say using RHEL for example), then [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1729855) might do the trick:

First check the SELinux context of your NVidia hardware:

```sh
$ ls -lZ /dev/nvidia*
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:xserver_misc_device_t:s0 195,   0 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:xserver_misc_device_t:s0 195, 255 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidiactl
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:xserver_misc_device_t:s0 243,   0 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidia-fs0
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:xserver_misc_device_t:s0 243,   1 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidia-fs1
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:xserver_misc_device_t:s0 243,  10 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidia-fs10
...
```

As you can see the security context does not allow for containers to access the device, so change the security context as per the documentation above:

```
$ chcon -t container_file_t /dev/nvidia*
```

Now check again the security context:

```
$ ls -lZ /dev/nvidia*
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0     195,   0 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0     195, 255 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidiactl
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0     243,   0 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidia-fs0
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0     243,   1 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidia-fs1
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0     243,  10 Dec 17 09:44 /dev/nvidia-fs10
...
```

This should allow your containers to access the hardware (at least for us it did the trick).

Answer (score 1):

### PC

```bash
sudo vim /etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml
```

edit `#user = "root:video"` => `user = "root:vglusers"`, save
maybe run `sudo nvidia-smi` and `sudo reboot -h`

---

### nvidia-docker

You need to execute `ll /dev/nvidia*` first to confirm the user:group of the nvidia device.

Then populate the group into the Dockerfile

```bash
echo "vglusers:x:1001:${USER} >> /etc/group
```

---

There is only one thing that is confusing at present is whether there is a variable with the content of 1001 in the system variables

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever installed VirtualGL?
I had the same problem, but I installed VirtualGL and it was a problem.
Run the VirtualGL installation file and select "Unconfigure server for use with VirtualGL". Then everything works normally.

IMPORTANT NOTE: Your system uses modprobe.d to set device permissions. You
must execute rmmod nvidia with the display manager stopped in order for the
new device permission settings to become effective.

Answer (score 0):

refer to [nvidia-docker github issue](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/1547)
modify  `/etc/nvidia-container-runtime/config.toml`
uncomment `user = "root:video"`
modify it to `user = "root:root"`

something else I did was that before I modify the config file, I delete the `vglusers` group

Answer (score 0):

To follow the answer of @Zealseeker:
Since my machine has several users I've changed the rights to rw-rw-rw- for following devices (I have two cards) :

```
ll /dev/nvidia

crw-rw-rw- 1 root vglusers 195,   0 Oct 13 19:34 /dev/nvidia0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root vglusers 195,   1 Oct 13 19:34 /dev/nvidia1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root vglusers 195, 255 Oct 13 19:34 /dev/nvidiactl
...
```

This idea was based on files at second machine, where there wasn't an update to driver nvidia-470.